# How to adjust the top margin of SSRS data bar chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I have a SSRS data bar chart (as shown below in Figure 1.0) in design mode which is perfectly fine.  But, when I run the report, the top margin on the chart expand (see on Figure 2.0)

Figure 1.0
[image]

Figure 2.0
[image]

I did some research but I couldn't find any viable solution related to this issue.  This data bar chart dynamic height property has an expression configured to display all the values in the y-axis.

The expression is

> =Switch(ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value <= 10, "1.8 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value = 20, "1.7 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value = 30, "1.6 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value = 40, "1.5 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value = 50, "1.4 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value > 50, (ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value - (ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value / 1.2)) & " in")

This is set in chart DynamicHeight

Does anyone encounter the same issue? How can I adjust/fix the top margin of the chart?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the expression.  Can you show us what it is?
Have you tried removing the expression and see what happens?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, thanks.  There is no issue in the expression.  It only calculates the height to which the chart should grow/shrink. The expression is `=Switch(ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value <= 10, "1.8 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value = 20, "1.7 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value = 30, "1.6 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value = 40, "1.5 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value = 50, "1.4 in", ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value > 50, (ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value - (ReportItems("HiddenTextBox").Value / 1.2)) & " in")`  This is set in chart DynamicHeight properties.

Comment: Actually, I have already fixed the issue.  What I did, I have enabled the chart  CustomInnerPlotPosition and CustomPosition.  By default this is disabled.  These properties can be seen in chart properties - ChartAreas (if using ReportBuilder) I have change the value of top position to `0` in CustomPosition and `1.5` in CustomInnerPlotPosition.  The extra padding on the top was trimmed then.  However, by doing that, there is now too much space between the last value of the chart and the bottom of the chart.

Comment: You should post that as an answer ;-)  Or if the bottom margin is an issue, add it to the question